# vb.net continue for inside a for each

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, continue

i have a for each loop inside a for loop, the for each loop checks if a value in some column in the current row exists in an array, if it exists i want to do whats in the for loop and if it doesnt exist i want to continue the for loop

```
for i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For Each id In IDs
            If (DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value <> id) Then
               'continue the for loop, by continue i mean using continue statement and not executing the outer for loop for this case
            End If
        Next
  'do for loop things
Next
```

what i am trying to do is to do calculations for the rows that have a specific id and skip the rows with the ids that are not in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to "do for loop things" only if there is a match? Why not just like this?

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 
    doThings = False
   For Each id In IDs
      If (DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value = id) Then 
        doThings = True
        Exit For
      End If 
  Next 
  If doThings Then 
    ** do for loop things 
  End If 
Next
```

Could be improved by creating more methods

- a function to determine whether an id appears in "IDs". Is it a List? Can you use IDs.Contains()
- a method to "do for loop things"

Comment: i've done it like this before, but i just wonder if there is another way

Comment: I don't think there's another way. But see my edit. I would extract some functions to tidy this code up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  Exit For to exit the inner For Each loop.  The outer For loop will be resumed where it left off.

**Exit For**

> Optional. Transfers control out of the For Each loop.
>
> When used within nested For Each loops, Exit For causes execution to exit the innermost loop and transfers control to the next higher level of nesting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx

```
for i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For Each id In IDs
            If (DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value <> id) Then
               Exit For 'continue the for loop
            End If
        Next
  'do for loop things
Next
```

Comment: but if the value is not found in the array want to use continue statement for the outer for loop–

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking not equal condition, check for equal condition.

```
for i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1         
    For Each id In IDs             
        If (DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value == id) Then
            'continue the for loop
        End If
    Next
    'do for loop things 
Next
```

Comment: but if the value is not found i want to use continue statement for the outer for loop

Answer (score 0):

[Exit Statement (Visual Basic) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx)

```
for i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    For Each id In IDs
        If (DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value <> id) Then
           Exit For ' Exit this For Each loop
        End If
    Next
'do for loop things
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The `doThings` answer is fine and readable, but to actually use a `Continue For` you need to change the inner `For` loop to one of the other loops availble to VB.NET.

```
for i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    Using EnumId As IEnumerator(Of String) = IDs.GetEnumerator
        'For Each id In IDs
      While EnumId.MoveNext
        Dim id = EnumId.Current
            If (DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value <> id) Then
               'continue the for loop, by continue i mean using continue statement and not executing the outer for loop for this case
               Continue For
            End If
        'Next
      End While
    End Using
  'do for loop things
Next
```

<sub>(Typed in without checking syntax in the IDE.)</sub>

Comment: There's probably also a LINQ answer that converts this to a single loop too.